# How to make the code more generic

Tags: scala

Here is my scala code with some example usage:

```
  object s {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    def apply[A <: In, B <: In](a: A, b: B) = foo(a, b)
    def apply[A <: Int, B <: In](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: TypeTag[B]) = foo(int(a), b)
    def apply[A <: In, B <: Int](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: TypeTag[A]) = foo(a, int(b))
    def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = foo(int(a), int(b))
    def apply(a: Int, b: Float) = foo(int(a), float(b))
    def apply(a: Int, b: Double) = foo(int(a), double(b))
  }

  case class int(b: Int) extends In {}
  case class float(b: Float) extends In {}
  case class double(b: Double) extends In {}

  case class foo[A <: In, B <: In](a: A, b: B) extends In {}


  def usage = {
      val a: struct[int, float] =   s(int(1), float(3.1f))  
      val b: struct[int, struct[int, int]] =    s(int(1), s(in
      val c: struct[int, int] =     s(3, int(5))              
      val d: struct[int, int] =     s(3, 7)                   
      val e: struct[int, double] =  s(6, 19.4)              
      val f: struct[struct[int, int], int] =    s(s(1, 1), 9) 

      // all above work fine
  }
```

how should I modify the code to accept any combination of primitive arguments without manually coding all methods overloading all combinations cases?

E.g so I can have:

```
def wanted = {
  s(34.4, 1.1)
  s(1.3f, 1.1)
  s(1.2, 123)
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Numeric` type to handle all numeric types instead of handling them one by one:

```
trait In

object s {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  def apply[A <: In, B <: In](a: A, b: B) = foo(a, b)
  def apply[A <: AnyVal : Numeric, B <: In](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: TypeTag[B]) = foo(numeric(a), b)
  def apply[A <: In, B <: AnyVal : Numeric](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: TypeTag[A]) = foo(a, numeric(b))
  def apply[A <: AnyVal : Numeric, B <: AnyVal : Numeric](a: A, b: B) = foo(numeric(a), numeric(b))
}

case class numeric[B <: AnyVal : Numeric](b: B) extends In

case class foo[A <: In, B <: In](a: A, b: B) extends In {}


def usage = {
  // these still work:
  s(3, numeric(5))
  s(3, 7)
  s(6, 19.4)
  s(s(1, 1.1), 9.1)  

  // now these work too:
  s(34.4, 1.1)
  s(1.3f, 1.1)
  s(1.2, 123)

  // and this doesn't - as expected:
  s(1, "bad!")
}
```

Comment: Well, almost. Before: val c: struct[int, int] = s(3, int(5)) val x: struct[int, struct[int, int]] = s(3, s(3, int(5))) after your change: val c: struct[In with Product with Serializable, int] = s(3, int(5)) val x: struct[In with Product with Serializable, struct[In with Product with Serializable, int]] = s(3, s(3, int(5))) It now breaks other part of my API

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to this problem:

```
  object s {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

    trait Pi[T] {
      type U <: In
      def convert(x:T): U
    }
    implicit val fooInt = new Pi[Int] { type U = int; def convert(x:Int) = int(x) }
    implicit val fooFloat = new Pi[Float] { type U = float; def convert(x:Float) = float(x) }
    implicit val fooDouble = new Pi[Double] { type U = double; def convert(x:Double) = double(x) }
    implicit def fooIn[T <: In] = new Pi[T] { type U = T; def convert(x:T) = x }

    def apply[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit pi1: Pi[A], pi2: Pi[B]) = {
      foo(pi1.convert(a), pi2.convert(b))
    }

  }

  case class int(b: Int) extends In {}
  case class float(b: Float) extends In {}
  case class double(b: Double) extends In {}

  case class foo[A <: In, B <: In](a: A, b: B) extends In {}


  def usage = {
      val a: struct[int, float] =   s(int(1), float(3.1f))  
      val b: struct[int, struct[int, int]] =    s(int(1), s(in
      val c: struct[int, int] =     s(3, int(5))              
      val d: struct[int, int] =     s(3, 7)                   
      val e: struct[int, double] =  s(6, 19.4)              
      val f: struct[struct[int, int], int] =    s(s(1, 1), 9) 

      // all above work fine
  }
```